bazel query to find all test targets and test
Team,
I want to find all test targets and run them.
I tried
./bazel test $(./bazel query //...) -//src/ui/...
output:
./bazel: Argument list too long
any hint what i could be doing wrong?

What does bazel query //... resolve to? That's what probably just too large for the commandline. Consider piping that into xargs or perhaps apply some kind of chunking.

BTW: As a general advise, I'd create an alias all_tests that runs all tests in a directory, including those is subdirs. That way you only need bazel test all_tests.

query resolves to huge list of paths. thanks I will consider the suggestions but for now I need command syntax help.

bazel test //... --build_tests_only -- -//src/ui/... should work. There's no need for bazel query based on the scope of your question.

it is including src/ui here > currently loading: src/ui/browse/api ... . I expect  to be ignored.

That loading message means that there are tests targets outside of //src/ui that depends on targets in //src/ui, and Bazel is loading those BUILD files in order to build those dependencies. Did you mean that you want to find test targets that have no dependencies in //src/ui/...?

ah no, I just meant to not load /src/ui at all and skip it completely

Bazel wouldn't load anything in //src/ui at all if the requested targets being built do not have a dependency in //src/ui. So if you're seeing this message, there is a dependency from some test outside of //src/ui into something in //src/ui. You can use bazel query somepath() to debug that.
